# Flutter request permission for camera doesn't work in iOS

Tags: flutter, permissions, camera

I don't get a prompt for permissions when I run the function:
I use iOS and have this line in my info.plist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> <string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>
```

```
 getPermissionStatus() async {
    await Permission.camera.request();
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    print(status);
    if (status.isGranted) {
      log('Camera Permission: GRANTED');
      setState(() {
        isCameraPermissionGranted = true;
      });
      // Set and initialize the new camera
      onNewCameraSelected(cameras[0]);
      refreshAlreadyCapturedImages();
    } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
      // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the
      // user manually enable it in the system settings.
      openAppSettings();
    } else {
      log('Camera Permission: DENIED');
    }
  }
```

The Log is allways...PermissionStatus.denied

Comment: make sure you have added camera permission as follow: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I use iOS and have this line in my info.plist
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you need to configure following things for getting permission dialog in iOS:

> Info.plist (as your updated question you already have added this in Info.plist)

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>
```

> Podfile  (you can find this in ios folder of project)

```
# Start of the permission_handler configuration
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'

      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
      ]

    end
# End of the permission_handler configuration
```

you can find more permission group of iOS in permission_handler documentation (scroll to Setup section of ios): [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

[image: Podfile code image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add camera permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: I use iOS and have this line in my info.plist <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> <string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>